# resource.data null error in the firestore rules simulator

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to filter out the posts by 'hidingUserId', so set rules are:

```
match /reviews/{userId=**} {
allow read: if resource.data.hidingUserId == null 
|| resource.data.hidingUserId != userId;
  allow delete, update, create: if request.auth != null;}
```

However, in rules simulator I am getting null value error on 'resource'. pls, see the pic [image: simulator rules]

and running debug on the phone returns 'Missing or insufficient permission'.

and my firestore is in the following order, where 'hidingUserId' is an array in the reviews database. [image: here]

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

**Why your simulator fails.**

`resource.data` contains the document data you want to fetch. If you try to fetch a document that does not exist, `resource.data == null` and you get that null value error.

`/reviews/userId` I don't think there is any document with `id = 'userId'`, so this will try to fetch a non existent document and Null value error will be thrown.

if you use an actual document in your simulator, it should pass true

**Why your debug device throws permission error**

This is your rule:

```
match /reviews/{userId=**} {
allow read: if resource.data.hidingUserId == null 
|| resource.data.hidingUserId != userId;
  allow delete, update, create: if request.auth != null;
}
```

Allow read if

1. `resource.data.hidingUserId == null`. hidingUserId is an array and is not null. Therefore this will be false.
2. `resource.data.hidingUserId != userId`. userId is a string, hidingUserId is an array. This should be return true.
   Your rule should pass (unintended).
   NB: userId above will contain forward slash.

For this, you should use @Dharmaraj suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have a recursive wildcard there `/reviews/{userId=**}` so the value of `userId` would be `"/userId"` and not just `"userId"` which would return false for sure. Also the `hidingUserId` seems to be an array so an equality won't work. Try removing the `=**` as shown below:

```
match /reviews/{userId} {
  allow read: if !(userId in resource.data.hidingUserId);

  allow delete, update, create: if request.auth != null;
}
```

Comment: thank you, @Dharmaraj. I used your suggestion, however, still getting null on the 'resource'...

Comment: @HaKim can you share a screenshot of that document from reviews collection?  Your path is `/reviews/userId` where userId is treated as a string. It's looking for a document with 'userId' as doc ID.

Comment: I tried match /reviews/{review}, also /reviews/{document=**}... nothing works. resource is still null. perhaps, the thing is that not all reviews have the array 'hidingUserId', because not all posts will be hidden by the user?

Comment: @HaKim keep it `match /reviews/{review}` but in your path in left side of the rules playground, change it to `/reviews/KeyRpm...` the ID of document in your screenshot instead of `/reviews/userId`

Comment: yes, i played around with set IDs and it works in simulator. however, not on my phone. i get: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}...